# Android Registering device on GCM results in SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I've several mobile applications, all using the same code, same manifest(different package names) and same permissions but different project numbers and api keys for gcm. The last project I deployed using the same code was last week and now it has around 20 devices registered and the last notification I've received from that application was last night. Today I've check the same project to see if I can register my device on gcm again and now I receive error message "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE", then I've checked few more projects and they also can't register on gcm and get the same error message. What could be the possible reason?

here's my manifest part for permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<permission android:name="vina.kaw.mp2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="vina.kaw.mp2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and registered my receiver in manifest as below:

```
<receiver
    android:name="vina.kaw.notification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="vina.kaw.mp2" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

as I mentioned above, the code was working perfectly fine since last week, but suddenly it's stopped working.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure what exactly was wrong, but after few times trying and getting the same error message, suddenly it started to work just fine as it was expected to work, can someone explain? is it because the server was busy at that moment? if yes then what is the best solution for me to implement to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

to your `<intent-filter>`

and add the below line:

```
<service android:name="vina.kaw.mp2.GCMIntentService" />
```

This is to add GCM service to your application

Comment: Are those mandatory to have in manifest? Because as I've updated my post, it's working fine now.

Comment: Aha thanks for clearing it up for me, well it's working at the moment so I assume it was google server being busy, do you mind if I ask you about the work around for when the service is not available ?

Comment: Actually GCMIntentService is for the Intent Service. which will help you to redirect to the user to your application from the notification, which will send by the GCM